# cups - Set default settings for ANY printers

Tags: cups, printer, settings

This is the configuration change I want for any printers added in the future:

```
ColorModel=Gray
cupsPrintQuality=High
```

Both `/var/cache/cups` and `/etc/cups` have per-printer settings, but I want them to work automatically for every new printer added in the future. I tried adding the above two values in the `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` file, with no effect. Obviously to verify this I turned off the printer, deactivated cups (this deleted the file in the `/etc/cups/ppd` directory and reset the `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file), deleted the printer options stored in `/var/cache/cups`, restarted the PC and turned on the printer again.

How do I make the new cups settings work automatically for every new printer I add?